# VSTO Outlook 2007 unique message ID

Tags: .net, vsto, outlook-addin, outlook-2007, outlook-object-model

I am creating an Outlook 2007 add-in using VSTO.  I need to store information (entered by the user) about each email.  My first thought is to create a small "database" that references each email as necessary.  But I can't seem to find an accessible identifier for each email for this purpose.  Is there an ID or some other unique field that is available for each mail message item that I can use?

C# or VB.NET code is fine.  Hopefully this can be some easy points for you!

Thanks in Advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The mail item has a number of properties, including [EntryID Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa211865%28v=office.11%29.aspx). You can also add [custom properties](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/907985).

Answer (score 1):

Outlook items have a unique EntryID and StoreID and you need them both to find the item later. 
For example, if you create a database that references Outlook emails, you might want a method for finding & opening the email in Outlook.
To retrieve an Outlook item, you need to know its EntryID and StoreID so you can pass the values to `NameSpace.GetItemFromID(EntryIDItem, EntryIDStore)`

You can read more about it here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/bb206749(v=office.12).aspx